# AWS Lambda API gives 502 error on POST request

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

POST request works fine for Lambda function and  API. However, when I hit it through Postman then it gives 502 internal Gateway error.

When I print request in Clouwatch logs for Postman POST request, I get the following:

```
{
"resource": "/{proxy+}",
"path": "/entitlement",
"httpMethod": "POST",
 "body": "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",
"isBase64Encoded": true
}
```

When I print request in logs for API Gateway, I get the following:

```
{
"resource": "/{proxy+}",
"path": "/entitlement",
"httpMethod": "POST",
"body": "{\"lastRenewal\":1532500221761,\"soldTo\":\"0001652453\",\"startDate\":1532500221761,\"expirationDate\":1535178621761,\"activationCode\":\"0449835557734402\",\"quantity\":0,\"version\":\"219\",\"term\":\"monthly\",\"active\":true,\"customerId\":null,\"firstName\":\"THIRD\",\"lastName\":\"TEST\",\"companyName\":\"Thirdtest\",\"cancellationDate\":null,\"email\":\"abc@xyz.com\"}",
"isBase64Encoded": false
}
```

GET request works fine. Face issue only for POST request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 'API-Gateway' console, expand API and select 'Settings' tab.
There is a field for 'Binary Media type', which was set to "*/*', due to which 'isBase64Encoded' is set to true in POST request.

However, my application was posting only json data in request body, so there is no need for 'binary support'. So we removed this field and it worked fine.

If you are posting binary data(images/files), in that case set 'Binary Media type' to respective file support type.

Comment: Is there some example for this? My Get endpoint will need to have an API gateway to return pdf files. How do I disable it in POST? I am using serverless to configure it and don't end up in the above situation